# NotificationListener's onNotification is not being called if child GridView doesn't have a fixed height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add an `event` at the end of `GridView` scroll. So I am using `NotificationListener`. But I noticed if I dont wrap the `GridView` in a `Container` with `height`, the `onNotification` of `NotificationListener` is not being called. How to solve this?
The `GridView` is inside a `Column`.

```
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(...),

                            NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                                  onNotification: _handleScrollNotification,
                                  child: GridView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    itemCount:
                                        _calculateListItemCount(state),
                                    controller: _scrollController,
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(...),
                                    gridDelegate:
                                        SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                                    ),
                                    primary: false,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      return index >= s.travelPlaces.length
                                          ? _buildLoaderListItem()
                                          : _buildListItem(
                                              s.travelPlaces[index],
                                              index,
                                            );
                                    },
                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  ),
                                ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

**_handleScrollNotification** function:

```
  bool _handleScrollNotification(ScrollNotification notification) {
    print("extenAfter : ${_scrollController.position.extentAfter}");
    if (notification is ScrollEndNotification &&
        _scrollController.position.extentAfter == 3) {
      BlocProvider.of<TravelplaceBloc>(context)
        ..add(TravelPlaceEvent.fetchNextTravelPlaces());
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: But a general context of a scrolling item is when something has a specific height and the context is more than the height instead to overflow then a scroll bar will show which will allow free flow of the data..

Comment: What I',m trying to say here is a scroll of content can only happened if there is a fixed height and the data content is more than the fixed height...
GridView doesn't have height unless you wrap it in a container where you can specify the height of the container.. only then your scrollnotification can work.

Comment: @DAMMAK Oh I see! But I need to use `GridView` without wrapping in a fixed height `Container`, any solution?